# JAX-WS service deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new to web service programming and trying to create a JAX-WS web-service. I have created the following [JAX-WS web service](http://www.tutorialscorner.com/webservice/JAX-WS-Tutorial.html) in Eclipse:

Creating the service interface:

```
package test;
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface AdditionService {  
    @WebMethod
    int add(int a,int b); 
}
```

After that one implementation class:

```
package test;
@WebService(endpointInterface = "test.AdditionService")
public class AdditionServiceImpl implements AdditionService{

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;     
    }
}
```

Last step:
By using the following code I am publishing the service:

```
package test;
public class AddtionServicePublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish
("http://localhost:9999/ws/additionService", 
new AdditionServiceImpl());

    }
}
```

I can view the wsdl using the bellow local URL:
`http://localhost:9999/ws/additionService?wsdl`

But as I don't have any server installed. How, it is getting published? Is server is inbuilt with eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html#publish(java.lang.Object)) states the following

> Creates and publishes an endpoint for the specified implementor object at the given address.
>   The necessary server infrastructure will be created and configured by the **JAX-WS implementation** using some default configuration.

As JAX-WS is part of the Java SE package, this means the underlying server is depending on what kind of JVM you are running your program at. E.g. on my laptop I am running a Java 8 OpenJDK, in which an instance of "com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer" is created.

The fastest way to find out what server ist started in your environment, just jump into the (decompiled) code of the Endoint.java and the implementation(s).

If you want to create a standalone, selfrunning Webservice-jar you might be interested to take a look at [Spring-WS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) (with Spring Boot) or [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/).